# Why !+[]+[]+![] is 'truefalse'?

Tags: javascript, type-coercion

As the title says. I'm learning coercion in JavaScript and I don't understand the return of that expression.

```js
const test = !+[]+[]+![];
console.log(test);
```

Comment: How can someone say that a question about javascript is a duplicate of a question about brainfuck?

Comment: @Bob I didn't vote to close it, but look at the answers in that link. The code _is_ based on Javascript. The OP says it _reminds_ them of brainfuck, not that it _is_ brainfuck.

Comment: Thanks @Liam, not I will hope that the author will accept it

Comment: @Bob The question wasn't "about brainfuck". It's asking to identify the language. The top answer states it's JavaScript and interprets what the difference sub-expressions mean. To mirror your first comment, I don't see why we need one Q&A pair for every single expression constructed with arrays. There is literally infinite amount of them. We don't need an infinite Q&As the same way we don't need one Q&A for each mathematical expression `1+1`, `1+2`, `1+3`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to be aware of how the expression is evaluated
so for expressions like this it could be useful to take a look on [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#table)

I will wrap the expressions with parenthesis and see how it goes. The logical not precedes addition (infix +)

```
!(+[])+([])+(!([]))
```

```
!(0)+([])+false
```

```
true+([])+false
```

Then when you try to evaluate `true+[]`  it will convert both to string and will result in "true", after that you will add `"true"+false`, `false` will be converted to string.